# Combine similar location directives into one

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'd like to combine these two directives into one, to avoid redundancy. They are both working.
Example urls are: `example.com/recipes/potatoes.pdf` or `example.com/media/recipes/potatoes.pdf`

```
location /recipes/ {
  rewrite ^/recipes/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/$1;
}

location /media/recipes/ {
  rewrite ^/media/recipes/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/$1;
}
```

When I combine them like this:

```
location ~ ^/(recipes|media/recipes)/ {
  rewrite ^/(recipes|media/recipes)/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/$1;
}
```

It doesn't 'work at all, but does not throw any errors. I assume that the filename is not matched correctly, but I cannot find the mistake. `proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/$1;` expects the pure filename, i.e. `proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/potatoes.pdf;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "combined" try, you introduce a second capture group in the rewrite regexp. So you need to also change the reference:

```
location ~ ^/(recipes|media/recipes)/ {
  rewrite ^/(recipes|media/recipes)/(.*) /$2 break;
  # --------------------------------------^^
  proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/$2;
  # ------------------------------------------^^
}
```

Alternatively, you can just **not** capture the part at all and combine even more.

I would go for:

```
location ~ ^/(?:media/)?recipes/ {
  rewrite ^/(?:media/)?recipes/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://$s3_bucket/media/recipes/$1;
}
```